# Show stacking column chart label value only if not equal to zero?

Tags: vb.net, charts

I have following code, original code is: [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/MSWinWebChart/thread/a4fccb7c-442a-4d56-a94c-c79fb7bef8b2)

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dtTest As DataTable = New DataTable
        dtTest.Columns.Add("col1", GetType(Integer))
        dtTest.Columns.Add("col2", GetType(Integer))
        dtTest.Columns.Add("col3", GetType(String))

        dtTest.Rows.Add(0, 1, "S")
        dtTest.Rows.Add(0, 1, "H")
        dtTest.Rows.Add(80, 1, "C")
        dtTest.Rows.Add(43, 2, "S")
        dtTest.Rows.Add(11, 2, "H")
        dtTest.Rows.Add(55, 2, "C")
        dtTest.Rows.Add(30, 3, "S")
        dtTest.Rows.Add(85, 3, "H")
        dtTest.Rows.Add(53, 3, "C")
        dtTest.Rows.Add(55, 4, "S")
        dtTest.Rows.Add(55, 4, "H")
        dtTest.Rows.Add(11, 4, "C")

        Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(dtTest)
        dv.Sort = "col2 asc"

        Chart1.Series.RemoveAt(0) 'this is just to remove the default Series in a 
        'VB.NET chart; you may not need this

        Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(dv, "col3", "col2", "col1", "Label=col1")

        For Each cs As Series In Chart1.Series
            cs.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Code generates chart below.. What I want to know if there is a way not to display a value on column if it is zero, like shown on left most column OR total value on the top of the column would be also good. I found how to do that in excel but did not manage to achieve for this program.

Thanks a lot for help

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to setup [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456203%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for your Series, I was able to get the result you were looking for by using the [Filter(CompareMethod,Double,Series)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd467929%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), along with [DataManipulator.FilterSetEmptyPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datamanipulator.filtersetemptypoints%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [DataManipulator.FilterMatchPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datamanipulator.filtermatchedpoints%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Properties.

**Modified Code**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dtTest As DataTable = New DataTable
    dtTest.Columns.Add("col1", GetType(Integer))
    dtTest.Columns.Add("col2", GetType(Integer))
    dtTest.Columns.Add("col3", GetType(String))

    dtTest.Rows.Add(0, 1, "S")
    dtTest.Rows.Add(0, 1, "H")
    dtTest.Rows.Add(80, 1, "C")
    dtTest.Rows.Add(43, 2, "S")
    dtTest.Rows.Add(11, 2, "H")
    dtTest.Rows.Add(55, 2, "C")
    dtTest.Rows.Add(30, 3, "S")
    dtTest.Rows.Add(85, 3, "H")
    dtTest.Rows.Add(53, 3, "C")
    dtTest.Rows.Add(55, 4, "S")
    dtTest.Rows.Add(55, 4, "H")
    dtTest.Rows.Add(11, 4, "C")

    Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(dtTest)
    dv.Sort = "col2 asc"

    Chart1.Series.RemoveAt(0) 'this is just to remove the default Series in a 
    'VB.NET chart; you may not need this
    Chart1.DataManipulator.FilterSetEmptyPoints = True 'Points that match filter will be marked as empty
    Chart1.DataManipulator.FilterMatchedPoints = True  'Filter points that match Filter criteria



    Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(dv, "col3", "col2", "col1", "Label=col1")

    For Each cs As Series In Chart1.Series
        Chart1.DataManipulator.Filter(DataVisualization.Charting.CompareMethod.EqualTo, 0, cs)   'Compare if equal to zero
        cs.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn
        Dim dpcp As DataPointCustomProperties = New DataPointCustomProperties

    Next

End Sub
```

**Result**

[image]